# Preserving visibility "view" of a method using delegate call to a view method

Tags: solidity, delegatecall, view

I am using a delegate call inside a view function to a view function in the implementation contract

The compiler throws an error meaning that the delegate call can change the state, therefore, can not be declared as "view".

I am using an upgradeable contract, so  I prefer not to use the fallback() function. What would then be the alternative to preserve state visibility when using a delegate.call to a view function?
Thank you very much!

Comment: I think the following is a relevant question: https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/82342/how-to-perform-delegate-call-inside-of-view-call-staticall

Comment: Could you share an example of that view function ??

Comment: It is not relevant, this behavior happens with any view function

Comment: you want to preserve that on solidity level (like your function would be ok to be used by other view functions ?) if that's the case I dont think it's possible

Comment: @minhhn2910, yes exactly, this is what the question is about

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Easiest way to resolve this issue would be writing a `fallback()` method considering first 4 bytes of calldata as a selector and matching it with necessary view functions. And you can freely use `delegatecall` inside `fallback()`:

```
fallback() external {
    bytes4 selector = bytes4(msg.data);
    if (selector == IActor.power.selector) {
        // ...
    }
    if (selector == IActor.height.selector) {
        // ...
    }
    // ...
}
```

One more solution:

```
interface IDelegatedFoo {
    function delegatedPower() external view returns(uint256);
}

contract Foo {
    address impl;
   
    function power() external view returns(uint256) {
        return IDelegatedFoo(address(this)).delegatedPower();
    }

    function delegatedPower() external /* view */ returns(uint256) {
        (bool success, bytes memory res) = impl.delegatecall(abi.encodePacked(this.power.selector, msg.data[4:]));
        require(success, "Failed delegatecall");
        return abi.decode(res, (uint256));
    }
}
```

Comment: Hey, thks, but the actually as stated in the question, I am asking for a solution without using fallback()

Comment: nops, I need to preserve the context and staticcall doesn't

Comment: @donoso.eth added one more solution to the answer.

Comment: Great! this works. Thank you very much

Comment: @donoso.eth provided code should also work with any possible arguments.

Answer (score 0):

When calling another smart contract using the standard way by specifying the interface of the smart contract being called and then calling that function as follows: `contract.functionName(params)`, the Solidity compiler checks if the target function is marked as "view" or "pure" in its interface. However, when using `delegatecall`, Solidity does not have knowledge of the exact function being called or whether it modifies the state or not.

A possible workaround would be to use the `staticcall` function instead of `delegatecall`. This would work as long as `staticcall` is not invoking a function where the calling context (storage/state-variables, msg.sender, msg.value, etc..) needs to be preserved. Since `delegatecall` preserves the calling context, while `staticcall` doesn't. `staticcall` works exactly the same as `call` with only difference that it cannot modify state of the contract being called.

Comment: This trick would not work for any functions touching storage - moreover it would return wrong result.

Comment: thks, not applicable in this case,as I need to preserve the context from the caller

Comment: @k06a Yes, that's true since the storage is also part of the calling context. I'll update the answer to make that clearer.